# How to show Yes No May be options in ICS calendar using Python

Tags: python, calendar

I am creating ICS file using python ics package:

```
calendar = Calendar()
        event = Event()
        event.name = jsonData['title']
        event.begin =  finalDate
        event.end = finalDate
        event.location = "Dhaka"
        event.organizer = jsonData['email']
        event.status = "TENTATIVE"
        event.description = "helllo"
        calendar.events.add(event)
```

Its working fine and showing Add to calendar » button with date time preview. So, I want to show Yes/No/May be option. I used to search but found some code that's not working.

```
event.add('attendee', 'yes')
event.add('attendee', 'no')
event.add('attendee', 'maybe')
```

and chatgpt suggested code is:

```
event.add('COMMENT', 'Yes')
event.add('COMMENT', 'No')
event.add('COMMENT', 'Maybe')
```

But none of these are working to display those 3 option. Let me know if you have implemented it.